# push-уведомление не исчезает

Tags: javascript

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        let count = this.getUnreadCount(this.props.unreadMessages);
        const prevCount = this.getUnreadCount(prevProps.unreadMessages);

        if (count !== prevCount) {
            if (count > 9) {
                count = "9+";
            }
            this.state.favicon.badge(count);

        }
    }
```

Суть такая. Если пользователь залогинен и не прочитает сообщение которое ему приходит, а потом разлогинется, то пуш будет висеть на вкладке

Comment: ну так скрой его при разлогинивании

Comment: знал бы как ) отредактировал и подставил код

Comment: как приведенный блок кода связан с заданным вопросом?

Comment: там не пуш, а фавикон висит на вкладке.

Comment: а почему тогда в заголовке вопроса про push?